# $f \in L^p(X, \mu)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left \| f_n \right \|_p^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $1<p< \infty$ and $\{E_n \}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets. Let $\{f_n \} \subset L^p(X ,\mu)$ be such that $f_n(x)=0$ if $x \notin E_n$ for each $n \geq 1$. Let $f= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$. Prove that $f \in L^p(X, \mu)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left \| f_n \right \|_p^p< \infty$

It's a lemma in proof of Riesz presentation theorem but i can't reach.

Answer (score 1):

You have, by Monotone Convergence, 
$$
\int |f|^p=\sum_n\int_{E_n}|f|^p=\sum_n\int|f_n|^p=\sum_n\|f_n\|^p.
$$

Comment: but hypothesis does not include condition $X= \bigcup E_n$

Comment: It doesn't. But $f=0$ outside of $\bigcup E_n $, so the distinction is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|f_n\|_p^p<\infty$.

Consider
$$F_n=\sum_{k=1}^N f_k.$$
Since the $f_k$ are disjointly supported,
$$\|F_n\|_p^p=\int|F_n|^p\,d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^n\int|f_k|^p\,d\mu
=\sum_{k=1}^n\|f_k\|_p^p.$$
By the Monotone Convergence Theorem,
$$\|f\|_p^p=\int|f|^p\,d\mu<\infty$$
and so $f\in L^p$.

Comment: i think $$\|F_n\|_p^p=\int|F_n|^p\,d\mu=\int|\sum_{k=1}^n f_k|^p\,d\mu$$

Comment: @NguyễnĐăngKhảiHoàn it comes to the same thing, by the disjointness of the $E_k$.